# How to annotate queryset if object in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a small social network where users can like posts. I am using Django 3.1.7. I have defined my model for the post as follows:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=False, default=None)
    user_like = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} posted \"{self.content}\" on {self.date_published}'
```

From my `views.py` I want to return the posts with an annotation of whether the current user has liked a given post.  I am trying as follows:

```
def index(request):

    posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(
        likes=Count('user_like')).order_by('-date_published')

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(
            likes=Count('user_like'), liked=request.user in 'user_like'.all).order_by('-date_published')
    
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        'post_form': PostForm(),
        'page_obj': page_obj
    })
```

But unfortunately, I can not make the query work. I assume that the part where I check if the user is in the relationship is wrong (`liked=request.user in 'user_like'.all`) as it is treating `'user_like'` as `str` and not as the field in the Post.

**How should I annotate the posts to include whether the user has liked them or not based on the `ManyToManyField` between them? Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

posts = Post.objects.annotate(
    likes=Count('user_like'),
    liked=Exists(Post.user_like.through.objects.filter(
        post_id=OuterRef('pk'),
        user_id=request.user.pk
    ))
).order_by('-date_published')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. The missing part for me was the `OuterRef` as I didn't know how to match the current Post of the queryset with the one in the inner query.

Comment: is there a need for prefetch_related() here since user_like is a manytomanyfield
i.e. Post.objects.prefetch_related('user_like').annotate(
    likes=Count('user_like'),
    liked=Exists(Post.user_like.through.objects.filter(
        post_id=OuterRef('pk'),
        user_id=request.user.pk
    ))
).order_by('-date_published')

Comment: @ray: no, since this is used as a subquery, `.prefetch_related` is only necessary to fetch items of the database *to the Django/Python layer*. There is no need for `.select_related`/`.prefetch_related` for filtering, annotating, subqueries, since these are all translated to the SQL query.